# Generating documentation for Ruby

Tags: ruby

What do you use for generating documentation for your Ruby files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [YARD](http://YARDoc.Org/).

Answer (score 3):

Use rdoc.

http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely worth considering [TomDoc](http://tomdoc.org/), which is used extensively by the folks at [GitHub](https://github.com/).